# Брейкпойнты в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoint

Доброго времени суток!

Использую eclispe в качестве IDE, и у меня возникла небольшая проблема с брейкпойнтами. У меня есть два проекта, один из которых подключен к другому. Когда-то давно я поставил в коде первого проекта брейкпойнт для отладки. И теперь постоянно, когда я запускаю программу под отладчиком, то срабатывает этот брейкпойнт. Это происходит, несмотря на то, что я уже давно удалил его в исходниках проекта (в java-afqkt). Но все равно при запуске под отладчиком у меня открывается class-файл, в котором стоит этот брейкпойнт. Как убрать его оттуда, чтобы он не срабатывал? В самих исходниках его уже давно нет. Пробовал ребилдить проекты, но не помогает. (((

Answer (score 1):

Надите файл workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/ИМЯ_ВАШЕГО_ПРОЕКТА/.markers и удалите его. Или поробуйте открыть проект, далее меню Window->Show view->Other... в открывшемся окне выберите Debug->Breakpoints. Отключите или удалите ненужное.